# Combinatorics strategie for order

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

At the moment I have to deal a bit with Combinatorics but I have some problems with it. Let's say I have following situation:

> Spend 1500 Euro to 4 people so that everyone has a multiple of 100 Euro. How many different ways are there to spend all this money to them?

I know that we have to choose without lay back and without order. If I look at such an exercise I always know if it is with or without lay back but I have great difficulty with the order. Can someone please explain to me why we have no order in this context or give me a strategie how I can easily check if the exercise is with or without order?

Comment: How many ways are there to divide 15€ amongst 4 people?

Comment: The answer is 816 because we choose (4+15-1) over (15) but I have no idea why it is without order...

Comment: Presumably though all Euros are the same, the $4$ people are not.  An *answer* may very well involve binomial coefficients even when order is somehow involved.

Comment: Oh, now I see what your actual question is and well... We cannot know for sure as some relevant information is missing. I'd say @André's assumptions are likely those the author had in mind, but didn't tell us.

Comment: You should google "stars and bars."  Essentially what you have here is to write $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4=15$ where each $x_{i}$ is a non-negative integer and represents the number of 100 euro bills the $i$th person gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to put 15 (k) balls (bills of €100) in four (n) boxes (people). It is a combination with repeation. It is with repeation because one can get multiple bills of €100, and the order doesn't matter because it doesn't matter for the final amount of money whether I give A €100 first and then B €100, or vice versa.

Therefore the number of times is $$ {n+k-1 \choose k} = {18 \choose 15} $$